# How to call SseEmitter just once from spring endpoint

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm listening to my  `/score` endpoint with JavaScript like so:

```js
var sse = new EventSource('/score');
sse.onmessage = function (evt) {
    var el = document.getElementById('scores');
    el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(evt.data));
    el.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
};
```

But for some reason it's like the endpoint it's called every second.

[image]

EventSource.**onmessage** documantation says:

> Is an **EventHandler** called when a message event is received, that is when a message is coming from the source

This is my `/score` endpoint:

```java
private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

@GetMapping("/score")
public SseEmitter getScore() {
 final SseEmitter sseEmitter = new SseEmitter();

 executorService.submit(() -> {
  try {

   //System.out.println(text);
   //sseEmitter.send(text);
   sseEmitter.send("ok");
   sseEmitter.complete();


  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 });

 return sseEmitter;
}
```

How can i trigger it only when i send a request manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of reading i managed to trigger the `/score` endpoint on every request, but i had to change the server side a lot.

```java
 @Autowired
    private MessageProcessor processor;

 @GetMapping(path = "/score", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<MyObject> receive() {
        return Flux.create(sink -> {
            processor.register(sink::next);
        });
    }
```

Now I'm returning a `Flux` object instead of a `SseEmitter` , because with Emitter i need constantly to send responses to the client.

I also created another endpoint `/send` , where i send my object with `POST`

```java
 @PostMapping("/send")
    public String send(@RequestBody MyObject event) {
        LOGGER.info("Received '{}'", event);
        processor.process(event);
        return "Done";
    }
```

---

Nothing is changed on the `Client` side, the pipe between `/receive` and `EventSource` shouldn't be terminated from the client. I only added a `JSON` parsing because now i've got a custom object.

```js
eventSource = new EventSource("/score");

eventSource.onmessage = function (evt) {
  var obj =JSON.parse (evt.data);
        
  var el = document.getElementById('scores');
   el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj.id+' '+obj.name+' '+obj.desc));
   el.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
};
```

### The key part was to use a MessageProccessor

```java
@Service
public class MessageProcessor {

 private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageProcessor.class);

 private List < Consumer < MyObject >> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList < > ();

 public void register(Consumer < MyObject > listener) {
  listeners.add(listener);
  LOGGER.info("Added a listener, for a total of {} listener{}", listeners.size(), listeners.size() > 1 ? "s" : "");
 }

 // TODO FBE implement unregister

 public void process(MyObject event) {
  System.out.println("Processing: " + event);
  listeners.forEach(c -> c.accept(event));
 }
}
```

> Another example of **Webflux** can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux)

### Output

- **Client**

[image]

- **Server** (The 4 objects i posted)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's because you never called `EventSource.close()` to close the connection. Since your eventSource doesn't have a terminating condition, your browser will repeatably call `/score`.

Comment: i'm looking for a server side solution, what if i close it and then an `event` is triggered? , i want to constantly listen to the endpoint

Comment: The code you posted is a client side issue. Your server code is behaving as expected. it sends a 'ok' then sse connection terminates from the server side.  The reason you keep seeing repeating 'ok' is the result of repeating retries from your client side EventSource.

Comment: i can't call though `close()` because i need to keep on listening to that endpoint, probably ill handle the message from the server side if i can't call it just once

Comment: So you are looking for a server side solution to what? You are unclear on explaining what you trying to do.

Comment: As the title says, I'm trying to find a way to trigger SSE just once, like do `send()` just once, so I can have one `ok` on the client side.

Comment: Probably that's not how SSE works, perhaps I can't trigger it by `GET` request

Comment: Ditto, this is a client side issue.  Your server code sends ok just once then it terminates. but your client is continously trying to reconnect by calling `/score`. Your server doesn't control how many requests your client makes. If you are trying to get `ok` just once, event stream is not a good fit and stick to regular req/resp with Http 1.1